# Knowing if activity is running on foreground or background

Tags: android, android-notifications, background-foreground

I use certain sounds to notify the user of certain events. However, I do not want the app to notify the user with sounds if the activity is not on foreground.

How can I check if the app is running on background or not?

Comment: What is processing those "certain events"? A `Service`? A `BroadacastReceiver`?

Comment: They are processed by a `GCMIntentService`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on mco's answer, your `GCMIntentService` needs to do something that will trigger work in a foreground activity of yours, if you have a foreground activity. Typically, you will do this by setting up your activities to respond to some sort of message in `onResume()` and removing that in `onPause()`.

"Some sort of message" could be:

- An `Intent` sent via `LocalBroadcastManager`
- An `Intent` sent via the classic `sendBroadcast()`
- A message via a message bus, like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- Etc.

Answer (score 3):

In the Activity cycle, onResume is called when the app becomes visible (foreground) and onPause is called when it is not visible (background).

You can use these functions to do whatever you want to do when the app is background/foreground.